# Node.JS server receives data character by character instead of line by line

Tags: node.js, telnet

I've got a simple Node.JS server:

```
//Module dependencies
var net = require('net')


//Create server
var server = net.createServer(function (conn) {

  // handle connection
  conn.setEncoding('utf8');

  conn.write(
      'Hi, please enter something: '
  );

  conn.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });

});


//Listen
server.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('\033[96m   server listens at *:3000\033[39m');
});
```

It is supposed to echo a client's input in server's console window. But when I connect to the server using telnet client, it does so by outputting character by character, while I would rather it output line by line on pressing Enter.

I know I cann collect all the input in the `conn.on` method, but can it be done on a lower level?

Answer (score 1):

That's because telnet flushes the TCP buffer after every character unless you use [linemode](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1184).

Comment: How to turn this option on in Windows 7 telnet client?

Comment: you have to implement the telnet protocol [rfc1184](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1184)